# Shared hosting: Use own domain to send mail

Tags: email, shared-hosting

My problem: I have a webhosting account on a shared server (cpanel) and am using it to send emails. When looking at the email's source in my mail client, I see that "received: from" shows the shared server's name (e.g. server55.verygoodserver.com) instead of my domain (whatever.com).

Is there a way to show my domain in the "received: from" area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Simple like that. Because this is not you server and a SMTP server has ever only ONE Name - which means that the "shared host" would be "your host".

THAT SAID: it is a total non-issue. Seriously.

If you want it changed, get your own server.